# In Final Fantasy VII, how are primary stats calculated upon level up?

Tags: java

I'm creating a stat level up calculator for Final Fantasy VII, and was reading through [a guide](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/130791-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/36775).

For leveling up on primary stats, it says "This difference is then capped at 0 to 11 inclusive", however I see the number can be calculated above 11, when testing with my java code:

```
// Dexterity
// cloud starting level(6)
int levelUp = 7; 
// cloud starting dexterity at level 6
dex = 6; 
// cloud rank curve is 6 (for dex), and is within 2-11 levelUp bracket, 
// so 6 is the number on table
baseNumber = 6; 
// cloud rank curve is 6 (for dex), and is within 2-11 levelUp bracket,
// so 72 is the number on table
gradient = 72; 

baselineStat = baseNumber + ((gradient * levelUp) / 100);

randomStatDifferenceOne = 1 + baselineStat - dex;
randomStatDifferenceTwo = 2 + baselineStat - dex;
randomStatDifferenceThree = 3 + baselineStat - dex;
randomStatDifferenceFour = 4 + baselineStat - dex;
randomStatDifferenceFive = 5 + baselineStat - dex;
randomStatDifferenceSix = 6 + baselineStat - dex;
randomStatDifferenceSeven = 7 + baselineStat - dex;
randomStatDifferenceEight = 8 + baselineStat - dex;

System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceOne);
System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceTwo);
System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceThree);
System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceFour);
System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceFive);
System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceSix);
System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceSeven);
System.out.println(randomStatDifferenceEight);
```

This gives me the following results with `Rnd(1-8)`:

> 6 
>   7 
>   8 
>   9 
>   10 
>   11 
>   12 
>   13

In the guide, he has the following level up stats calculated for the different numbers (that should only be 0-11):

> - Difference | Stat Gain
> - 0-3    |     0
> - 4-6    |     1
> - 7-9    |     2
> - 10-11   |     3

In Final Fantasy VII, how are stat numbers above 11 and below 0 handled?

Comment: Looks to me like it means clamp the difference to [0, 11]. Any value below 0 becomes 0 and any number above 11 becomes 11.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted a few opinions to come to this conclusion before putting it in my program (I just hate logic bugs).

Comment: @Gnemlock Please leave the question wording as is and do not edit it. My question was very specific boiled down to how to handle a step in the level up formula used in the game. Also... this question was already asked in arcade and they told me to ask here (as I have already stated in my question before you edited it out). You tell me to go back there and ask. They tell me to come here and ask. I'm not going to pingpong until I get an answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is a shame Arcade didn't take the question being how the game works. Here how a game was done is often regarded as off topic. Instead how to make a game that implements the same mechanic is perfectly welcome here.

Comment: @Theraot I am making a calculator to implement the same mechanic (as I thought this would have fallen as being "welcome here"). It's to help players play through the perfect game challenge.

Comment: @Gnemlock technically, I am asking about how a game was developed -> or how a mechanic in a game was developed (same thing?)

Comment: You are not making a game with this mechanic, although I do not see that as the issue. The problem is that it depends to how FFVII works because it is a calculator meant to work for that game. Therefore, you cannot approximate it, but match the behavior perfectly. As such it would require to reverse engineer it or have a way to get the developers to answer... and there is no guarantee that that can be done. Even if left open, you may not get a suitable answer.

Comment: We have discussed whether we consider "how was a mechanic developed" on topic, [here is an example meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/why-should-how-was-the-technique-in-x-done-be-considered-off-topic/1077#1077), and the conclusion is a collective "no".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the mechanics of an existing video game; not about game developing, itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This difference is then capped at 0 to 11 inclusive

means that when the difference is smaller than 0, it is set to 0 and when it is larger than 11, it is set to 11.

Example:

```
randomStatDifferenceOne = 1 + baselineStat - dex;
if (randomStatDifferenceOne < 0) {
    randomStatDifferenceOne = 0;
}
if (randomStatDifferenceOne > 11) {
    randomStatDifferenceOne = 11;
}
```

Disclaimer: That's what *the guide* says. I have no idea if that's how FF VII actually works.

By the way: Whenever you start naming variables `VarOne`, `VarTwo`, `VarThree` etc., you should really be using an array or an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Whenever you want to do something with all of them, you should be using a [for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Thanks, I ran multiple tests with all positive results to confirm your answer is correct. As for the suggestion on multiple varNums, the code I presented here was just thrown together (not meant to be clean/re-factored yet). I turned it into a function using a for-loop that returns an array. This code is really just documenation code to show the coder the formula used to acquire the calculation results. The real code as part of the application is much different. Never-the-less, thanks for the advice.